# _exists? Ruby Sequel Activerecord equivalent

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rubygems, sequel

Does Ruby Sequel have equivalent methods for column_exists and index_exists? I couldn't find anything in the docs.

```
db = MyApp::Base.db_base

db.column_exists?(:table, :column)
db.index_exists?(:table, :column)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sequel doesn't have the same methods, but allows you to perform the same actions:

```
# column_exists?
db.schema(:table_name).map(&:first).include?(:column_name)
# index_exists?
db.indexes(:table_name).values.map{|x| x[:columns]}.include?([:column_name])
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a problem when determining whether an index exists or not.
Maybe this will help you too.
I'm using gem Sequel version 5.57.0.

The command above does not find the index.

```
db.indexes(:table_name)
=> []
```

However, I know for sure that the index exists.
And I tried to get the information in another way:

```
db.fetch("SHOW INDEX FROM `table_name`").all
=> [{:Table=>"table_name",
  :Non_unique=>1,
  :Key_name=>"table_name_created_at_index",
  :Seq_in_index=>1,
  :Column_name=>"created_at",
  :Collation=>"A",
  :Cardinality=>0,
  :Sub_part=>191,
  :Packed=>nil,
  :Null=>"YES",
  :Index_type=>"BTREE",
  :Comment=>"",
  :Index_comment=>""}]
```

You can check if there is an index as follows:

```
def index_exists?(table:, index_name:)
  db.fetch("SHOW INDEX FROM `#{table}` WHERE Key_name='#{index_name}'").all.present?
end

index_exists?(table: 'table_name', index_name: 'table_name_created_at_index')
=> true
```

P.S.
Be careful with the ` and ' characters